# spring-integration: how to deliver deferred details as SSE

Tags: spring-integration, server-sent-events, spring-integration-dsl

I have a list of items which I want to retrieve and return as fast as possible.

For each item I also need to retrieve details, they may be returned a few seconds later.

I could of course create two different routes with HTTP gateways and request first the list, then the details. However, I then have to wait until all details have arrived. I want to send back the list immediately and then the details as soon as I get them.

**UPDATE**

Following Artem Bilan's advice my flow returns a Flux as payload which merges the list of items as a Mono and the processed items as a Flux.

Note that the example below simulates detail processing of the items by calling `toUpperCase`; my real use case requires routing and outgoing calls to get the details for each item:

```
    @Bean
public IntegrationFlow sseFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(WebFlux.inboundGateway("/strings/sse")
                    .requestMapping(m -> m.produces(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE))
                    .mappedResponseHeaders("*"))
            .enrichHeaders(Collections.singletonMap("aHeader", new String[]{"foo", "bar"}))
            .transform("headers.aHeader")
            .<String[]>handle((p, h) -> {
                return Flux.merge(
                        Mono.just(p),
                        Flux.fromArray(p)
                                .map(t -> {
                                    return t.toUpperCase();
                                    // return detailsResolver.resolveDetail(t);
                                }));
            })
            .get();
}
```

That comes closer to my goal. When I request data from this flow using curl, I get the list of items immediately and the processed items slightly later:

```
λ curl http://localhost:8080/strings/sse
data:["foo","bar"]

data:FOO

data:BAR
```

While simply converting the string to uppercase works fine, I have difficulty to make an outgoing call for details using `WebFlux.outboundGateway`. The `detailsResolver` in the commented out code above is defined as follows:

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface DetailsResolver {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "itemDetailsFlow.input")
    Object resolveDetail(String item);

}

@Bean
IntegrationFlow itemDetailsFlow() {
    return f -> f.handle(WebFlux.<String>outboundGateway(m ->
            UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://localhost:3003/rest/path/")
                    .path(m.getPayload())
                    .build()
                    .toUri())
            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
            .expectedResponseType(JsonNode.class)
            .replyPayloadToFlux(false));
}
```

When I comment in the `detailsResolver` call and comment out `t.toUpperCase`, the `outboundGateway` seems to be set up properly (the log says Subscriber present, Demand signaled) but never gets a response (doesn't reach a breakpoint in `ExchangeFunctions.exchange#91`).

I have ensured that the `DetailsResolver` itself is working by getting it as a bean from the context and invoking its method - that gives me a JsonNode response.

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I wouldn't use `toReactivePublsiher()` there because you have a context of the current request. You need fluxes per request. I would use something like `Flux.merge(Publisher<? extends I>... sources)`, where the first `Flux` is for items and the second is for details per item (something like `Tuple2`).

For this purpose you really can use something like this:

```
  IntegrationFlows
                .from(WebFlux.inboundGateway("/sse")
                        .requestMapping(m -> m.produces(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)))
```

And your downstream flow should produce `Flux` as a payload for reply.

I have a sample like this in test cases:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sseFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(WebFlux.inboundGateway("/sse")
                        .requestMapping(m -> m.produces(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE))
                        .mappedResponseHeaders("*"))
                .enrichHeaders(Collections.singletonMap("aHeader", new String[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" }))
                .handle((p, h) -> Flux.fromArray((String[]) h.get("aHeader")))
                .get();
    }
```

Comment: That helps a lot, especially the point that the resulting payload must be a merged Flux. I have updated the question accordingly, but now my question is, how can I stick to the spring-integration API to process the item details? IOW, how can I write an IntegrationFlow so that it can be used as a Flux? Neither `IntegrationFlows.from()` nor `IntegrationFlow flow = flow -> flow.toReactivePublisher()` do the trick for me.

Comment: No, it is not. You need the flux per request. An IntegrationFlow is a singleton per application. If you would go that way, the flux is going to be shared for every http request. That isn’t what requested in your question

Comment: I have tried to make an outgoing call via a MessagingGateway from inside the details Flux (see question update). Should this be possible at all?

Comment: I would stay with the `replyPayloadToFlux(true)` to really expect reply from that `WebFlux.<String>outboundGateway()`...

Comment: Your `detailsResolver.resolveDetail(t)` has really to return  a `Flux<?>`. That's what is produced by the `WebFlux.outboundGateway()` with the `replyPayloadToFlux(true)`.

Comment: There must not be  `Flux.fromArray(p)` anymore: you just need to place there a `detailsResolver.resolveDetail(t)` call instead.